# javascript to animated a slide show isn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, slider, carousel

i have 2 slideshows on my Bootstrapped page. They use the carousel scripts and they work fine when I was testing on a demo page. Once it got into WordPress they slide if you manually click the navigation but not automatically.

These are the scripts:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Carousel').carousel({
interval: 4000
})
});
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#Carousel2').carousel({
interval: 4000
})
});
</script>
```

The interval is the speed to slide to the next frame and it stays on the one. But the manual navigation works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I see some errors in your code. Looks like your `<script>` tag is not closed correctly. Also, I cleaned up your code a bit so you're only using one document ready function. Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Carousel,#Carousel2').carousel({
          interval: 4000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I used it and it didn't change anything. It's not automatically animating. Is there any chance WordPress alters javascript or blocks something?

Comment: Turns out it was something in the wp_footer. Now my animations work but now the main nav on the homepage doesn't drop down menus.